# Why does A record give SERVFAIL when CNAME record does not fail

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

If I run

```
dig @ns5.laposte.net conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr A
```

I get a SERVFAIL, but if I run

```
dig @ns5.laposte.net conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr CNAME
```

I got my CNAME:

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48072
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr. IN    CNAME

;; ANSWER SECTION:
conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr. 300 IN CNAME prod-lbpee.web-application-front-customer.as8677.net.
```

I was wondering how valid this behavior could be (at least to know if we can expect that to happen more often), and from the [RFC 1034](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034) I can see:

- `If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present`
- `When a name server fails to find a desired RR in the resource set associated with the domain name, it checks to see if the resource set consists of a CNAME record with a matching class.  If so, the name server includes the CNAME record in the response`

So I believe this is not standard behavior. I also do not see any advice in "[Common DNS Operational and Configuration Errors](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1912#section-2.4)". Does anyone have recommendations or experience with that kind of issue? I guess here is just to look for a CNAME if a name server replies with a REFUSED or SERVFAIL?

Comment: "So I believe this is not standard behavior." It is kind of covered by https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034#section-4.3.1 see the part starting with "If recursive service is not requested or is not available, the non-
recursive response will be one of the following:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for you not getting recursive answers (which you want in a case like this, where a CNAME points at a CNAME that points at an A) is printed in your answer:
`;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available`

That means, the nameserver you are asking (ns5.laposte.net) is an authoritative nameserver, not a recursive one (also know as a resolver). It will only look into its database and see if there is a record of the type you are looking for, In your case, it looks for an A record for conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr, which doesn't exist. When explicitly setting the record type to CNAME you get the answer you expect, but nothing more (ie. the CNAME isn't followed). If you check on a recursive nameserver, dig will get recursive results until the A record is found:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.0 <<>> conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24724
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr. IN        A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr. 299 IN CNAME prod-lbpee.web-application-front-customer.as8677.net.
prod-lbpee.web-application-front-customer.as8677.net. 299 IN CNAME prd-lbpee.web-application-front-customer-as.lbp-mail.as8677.net.
prd-lbpee.web-application-front-customer-as.lbp-mail.as8677.net. 2670 IN A 160.92.71.152
```

Answer (score 3):

By default `dig` sets the RD (recursion desired) bit in queries, which means dig normally sends recursive queries.

With that disabled you will get the respond that you expect:

```
dig +norecurse @ns5.laposte.net conversation.ees.labanquepostale.fr
```